# How to configure Hudson to display code coverage results for MsTest without NCover?

Tags: visual-studio, hudson, mstest, code-coverage, hudson-plugins

My Hudson already builds and run the MsTest tests in my solution.
I already do see Code Coverage metrics in Visual Studio and I'm generating the coverage file in the build.
I don't have NCover.
How to make Hudson to show the coverage metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the list of available Hudson plugins [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything to meet your needs unless you use NCover. Is there a reason you can't use it or don't want to?

Comment: Because I would have to buy it. What puzzles me is that it has a SourceForge page, so maybe it has a free version.

Comment: I figured it out. NCover 1.5.8 is free while NCover 3 costs at least $99.

Comment: But the free version doesn't support some features of C# 3 and .NET 3.5

Comment: Depending on your needs and the version of the .NET Framework you are using, you might have to purchase NCover. I don't see this as a bad investment. Just make sure it's what you want. Try the free version for now and see what you can get out of it.

Comment: Actually there is the partcover plugin - which is free and handles .NET2 and .NET4 runtimes (assuming you get the latest one from github).

Comment: @Shaun Wilde: It seems like [this](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/PartCover+Plugin) plugin is still under development.

Comment: Perhaps but the page was last updated Nov 26 2010 - perhaps more progress has been made than actually documented. However PartCover is an alternative to NCover in a build environment such as hudson (and free)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first creating an xml file out of the binary (.coverage) file visual studio creates. Follwoing two links show how to achieve this task. They work like a charm.

http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2011/09/convert-mstest-code-covarage-results-in.html

[Merging Visual Studio Code Coverage fails with ImageNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536738/merging-visual-studio-code-coverage-fails-with-imagenotfoundexception)